# Hiding/trimming a part of the original route and redirecting to it

Tags: angular, angular-router

Im working on angular 4 and i want to trim a part of my current slug and resolve it into the same component as the original slug such that the user cannot see the original slug in the params.

I have a route `route/:slug` which resolves into and object and renders the component with that object called `EventDetail.component`.

My question is, is it possible to trim a part of that slug so that 
my `route/this-is-the-slug-by-person` becomes `route/this-is-the-slug`, and it resolves into the same component: `EventDetail.component`

this is my route which resolves into the event

```
{
    path: 'route/:slug',
    component : EventDetailComponent,
    resolve: {
        event: resolverService 
    }
}
```

i want a route

```
{
    path:'route2/:trimmedSlug,
    component : EventDetailComponent,
    resolve: {
      ...
    }
}
```

my resolveService

```
resolve () {
   return this.service.getEvent(this.route.params['slug']);
}
```

Is there any elegant way to do this?
Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Location.replaceState](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#replaceState).

```
constructor(public location: Location) {
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
    const slug = paramMap.get('slug');
    const trimmed = ...;
    this.location.replaceState(trimmed);
  })
}
```

Make sure to import `Location` from `@angular/common`;

Comment: Glad I could help :)